# How to sum up two json values in java android?

Tags: java, android, json, sum

Can any one tell me, how to sum two JSON objects values? Say, for an example:

**First JSON**

```
{
  "json_obj":20,
}
```

**Second JSON**

```
{
  "json_obj":40,
}
```

Here what I wanted is, I'm trying to create one JSON as same as like the above one, but i need to sum up two values of the JSON object "**json_obj**" and finally need to show it as like the below JSON

**Resultant JSON**

```
{ 
  "json_obj":60 
}
```

How to achieve this?

Comment: Um, fetch both values as numbers, add them, then create a new object with the same key and the new value? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Parse the value from first json and store it in an arraylist or an array.Repeat the same for the second json.Then add elements of the arraylist or the array,you will get the sum,then build the 3rd json with the sum

Comment: Do you have only one value in one json or multiple values ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
public String getAddedValues(String firstJson, String secondJson, String key){

    JSONObject first = new JSONObject(firstJson);
    JSONObject second = new JSONObject(secondJson);

    int value = first.getInt(key) + second.getInt(key);

    JSONObject output = new JSONObject();
    output.put(key, value);
    return output.toString();
}
```

Invoke it passing your json Strings and the "json_obj" String as key.

The idea is that you forst need to **convert the json string into a Java object**. Then you do your calculations, and finally you create another JSONObject with the result. JSONObject.toString() returns the common String representation you would expect as output :-)

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
JSONObject jsonObject1 = new JSONObject(First_JSON);
JSONObject jsonObject2 = new JSONObject(Socond_JSON);

JSONObject jsonObject3 = new JSONObject();
jsonObject3.put("json_obj", jsonObject1.getInt("json_obj")+jsonObject2.getInt("json_obj"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like that:

```
public class CalcObj {
    public int json_obj;
}

public String sumTwoJsons(String json1, String json2) {    
     Gson _gson = new Gson();

     CalcObj obj1 = _gson.fromJson(json1, CalcObj.class);
     CalcObj obj2 = _gson.fromJson(json2, CalcObj.class);

     CalcObj objSum = new CalcObj();
     objSum.json_obj = obj1.json_obj + obj2.json_obj;

    return _gson.toJson(objSum );
}
```